# Get value of Pulumi Secret in list

Tags: python, list, pulumi, pulumi-python

As part of a Pulumi Python project, I need to loop over certificates stored in the Pulumi YAML config file, and pass into a function creating the certificates.

The certificates are stored in a list in the YAML file, with the values "name", "value" and "password", where "value" and "password" is Pulumi Secrets.

I am struggling on getting the secrets from the list and passing into my create_certificate function. I have done various attempts with `apply` and similar but struggle getting it to work.

The Pulumi YAML file looks like this:

```yaml
config:
  myapp-env:certificates:
    - name: my-web-cert
      password:
        secure: xxx
      value:
        secure: yyy
  myapp-env:certificates:
    - name: second-web-cert
      password:
        secure: xxx
      value:
        secure: yyy
  myapp-env:env: dev
  myapp-env....
```

__main__.py:

```py
def create_certificate(
    name, rg_name, environment, location, password, value, tags=None, dependsOn=None
):

    certificate = Certificate(
        resource_name=name,
        certificate_name=name,
        environment_name=environment.name,
        location=location,
        resource_group_name=rg_name,
        properties=CertificatePropertiesArgs(password=password, value=value),
        tags=tags,
        opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(depends_on=dependsOn)
        if dependsOn
        else pulumi.ResourceOptions(),
    )

    return certificate
...

certificates = config.get_object("certificates")
if certificates:
    for certificate in certificates:
        name = certificate.get("name")
        password = x
        value = x

        cert = create_certificate(
            name=name,
            rg_name=rg,
            environment=managed_env,
            password=password,
            value=value,
            tags=tags,
            dependsOn=managed_env,
            location=location,
        )
```